# Protractor element.all

Tags: javascript, protractor

In Protractor, will the following be asynchronous or add something to the control flow, or is it lazy and will only be evaulated against the DOM when an action like `click` is performed?

```
element.all(by.css('.prices-container .quidget'))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) says:

> an ElementArrayFinder will not actually retrieve the elements until an action is called, which means it can be set up in helper files (i.e. page objects) before the page is available, and reused as the page changes.